# SubImages not showing on MultiScaleImage when zoomed out. How to show them?

Tags: silverlight, deepzoom, multiscaleimage

I've created a deep zoom image with nearly 200 SubImages. I just loaded the main image into Deep Zoom Composer and loaded all the SubImages and exported. I then used code to position and scale the SubImages by editing the dzc_output.xml.

All seems fine apart from when I show the image. Only the SubImages from mid way down up the image show.

When I zoom in on areas where I know there should be SubImages, they do appear.

I'm I hitting some kind of limit with MultiScaleImages or is there a way to control the 'zoom' level that an image shows in the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Worked it out.

Using Fiddler2 I noticed several 404, Silverlight was looking for image files in a path with /dzc_output_out_images/ as part of the path. Which didnt exist.

I'd changed the name of the dzc_output.xml file to dzc_output_out.xml.

Change the name back, all images are appearing now.